# Elastic Search Wildcards With Whitespace issue

Tags: elasticsearch

Prepared an ES query to find all records, which contain my substring (basically LIKE in SQL):

```
GET index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "companyName": {
              "value": "*test exactly*"
            }
          } 
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

It doesn't return records with companyName "Profile Test exactly" or f.e. "Subtest exactly".
How can I resolve this issue?

Tried the same with regex queries, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using regexp like this

```
{"regexp": {"companyName.keyword: {"value": ".*test exactly.*", "case_insensitive": True, "max_determinized_states": 10000}}}
```

In case you have `.keyword` field for `companyName` than only that will work to search texts with whitespaces. 
If you don't have `companyName.keyword` field and the whitespace searching is not working, than you need to update your index mapping to get this field.

PS: When a new field is added to index, ES automatically creates a `.keyword field` for it too (if you don't specify mapping for that field yourself).
The below image is Elasticsearch Tools visualization of fields of an index
[image]